# MySQL joining across databases from different AWS RDS instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Our database architecture consists of a global central database instance and multiple client database instances. It was working just fine for joining tables from different databases by supplying the prefix in table name when those databases were in the same server.

Now, we are splitting up the databases. They will be served in different instances on AWS. Is there anyway to join those tables from different databases located in different instances?

If not, what is the best solution rather than re-constructing all the queries?

Comment: Good question. The standard MySQL solution would be federated storage, but that's not supported on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

Comment: If I use federated engine, do I still have all features of InnoDB (transaction for example)? Updated: I didn't see that AWS does not support federated engine, but question still apply for knowledge

Comment: `FEDERATED` has limited support for transactions on MariaDB but not MySQL.  @MattS is not incorrect, but that's only a limitation in one direction.  An RDS instance can be the *target* of a `FEDERATED` connection, where a non-RDS MySQL or MariaDB server uses a federated connection to access data on the RDS machine.  I do that regularly for report generation.  The RDS machine can't access anything the other direction.